# Limits and inequality

Tags: limits, inequality

We want to find the largest $p>0$ such that
[image: Open this image]

for every $t>0$.

The official solution says,
Let $t$ go to infinity. Then $LHS\to \frac{1}{p}$, so $\frac{1}{p}\geq \frac{3}{2p+2}$.
Why does this inequality hold? Can it be shown by epsilon and delta reasoning? Because the LHS may not be equal to 1/p.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{t^3}{(t^2+1)(pt+1)}+\frac{t}{(t+1)(pt+1)}+\frac{1}{(t+1)(t^2+p)}\ge\frac{3}{2(1+p)}$$

Consider each term separately:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t^3}{(t^2+1)(pt+1)}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{p+\frac{1}{t}+\frac{p}{t^2}+\frac{1}{t^3}}=\frac{1}{p}$$

for the first fraction,

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{(t+1)(pt+1)}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{pt+p+1+\frac{1}{t}}=0$$

for the second, and

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{(t+1)(t^2+p)}=0$$

for the third. Because limits add, we know that $\frac{1}{p}+\epsilon\ge\frac{3}{2p+2}$ holds for all $\epsilon>0$, which means $p\le2$. Of course one still has to verify that it holds for $p=2$.